# Code coverage for coded UI automation test suite

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, code-coverage, coded-ui-tests

I am working on a ASP.NET web app and I want to get the code coverage on the same application by the Coded UI automation test suite we currently have. Is it possible to get the code the code coverage with the DLLs that I have or do we necessarily need to use the instrumented build for it? And if instrumented build is a must how do we instrument the build in order to get the code coverage on it? Any pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So I guess there is not much info out there on the internet related to this (Actually there is a lot but non-compiled and un useful info).  Here are the few links which we found out after searching :

1. Using Dynamic code coverage tool :- This tool works fine with newer versions [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/189a3068-8d0a-4e57-a13b-13c34de3b35d/how-to-use-dynamic-code-coverage-tools-from-command-line-in-visual-studio-2011?forum=vststest) should help while using this tool.
2. Using VSInstr :- [This](http://automationbyexample.blogspot.in/2013/04/visual-studio-2010-code-coverage-of-iis.html) guy has put a lot of efforts to document it completely. This works for older versions of .NET  applications.

Hope this helps.